# What is the right jquery selector to get a span next to the current item I am looking at?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html below and I am looping through and updating both the textbox and html inside the span for all items.

```
    <table>
            <tr>
                 <td>
                      <input type="text" class="myText" />
                      <span class="mySpan"></span>
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td>
                      <input type="text" class="myText" />
                      <span class="mySpan"></span>
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td>
                      <input type="text" class="myText" />
                      <span class="mySpan"></span>
                 </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

currently my jquery looks like this where i am looping through the class selector

```
   $('.myText').each(function (index, data) {

        $(data).val("Test");

        //I now want to reference the "mySpan" span that is right after the input item in question
   });
```

What is the best way to reference the respective "mySpan" span inside the .each() loop?

Comment: `$(this).next('.mySpan');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.myText').each(function (index, data) {
    $(data).val("Test");
    $(this).parent().find('.mySpan').text("Span Text");
});
```

Check this  on [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntqkptpe/)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do it:

```
$(this).next(); //match any following sibling

$(this).next('span.mySpan'); //match the following sibling if it's <span class=mySpan>

$(this).siblings('span.mySpan'); //match all siblings with that signature

$('.mySpan', $(this).parent()); //match all .mySpan-s in the parent of the current element
```

Ref [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method

Something like this

```
$('.myText').each(function (index, data) {
     $(data).siblings().css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```

And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxrxnh6e/)